# Correctly serving drinks in a cafe problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Five friends go into a cafe, sit at a table and order 3 coffees and 2 teas.  The waiter brings the drinks to the table and randomly serves the drinks to the five friends.

How do I compute the following?

1. The probability that the first served drink was a correct match
2. The probability that the first two served drinks were correct matches

Attempt:

1. Coffee is given to someone who orders coffee, or tea is given to someone who orders tea.

$\frac{3}{5}$ $\cdot$ $\frac{3}{5}$ + $\frac{2}{5}$ $\cdot$ $\frac{2}{5}$ = $\frac{13}{25}$. Am I doing it right?

2. I don't know how to appraoch this 2nd one. Any help is much apprecaited.

Answer (score 1):

The first two drinks served were coffee, and these matched, has a probability of:

$$\frac35\frac24\frac35\frac24=\frac{36}{400}$$

Similarly for CT:

$$\frac35\frac24\frac35\frac24=\frac{36}{400}$$

TC:

$$\frac25\frac34\frac25\frac34=\frac{36}{400}$$

TT:

$$\frac25\frac14\frac25\frac14=\frac{4}{400}$$

Adding gives the answer as $\frac{112}{400}=\frac{7}{25}$.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you got $\frac{3}{5}$$\frac{2}{4}$$\frac{3}{5}$$\frac{2}{4}$ for the CC and the rest? I don't quite get how you got those fractions.... Thanks in advance

Comment: @DumbMathematician The probability that the first person chosen to receive a drink prefers coffee, given that... then the probability that the second person chosen to receive a drink also prefers coffee, given that... the probability that the first drink grabbed by the waiter was a coffee, followed finally by given all of these the probability that the second drink grabbed by the waiter was also a coffee.  Multiplying gives the result.

Comment: If the first drink was C, then there are 2C's and 2T's left, which is four drinks. If the first drink was T, then there are 3C's and 1T left (still 4 drinks). The serving of the drinks follows a very similar pattern to who ordered what.@DumbMathematician

Comment: @JMP Thank you for your reply. Can you confirm if my answer to part 1 is right?

Comment: Yes it is, by [total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).